# Object dependencies, member variables (homework example)

Tags: php, class, function

I'm in the process of creating a wool farm, where sheep are sheared in the machine if they are old. The wool is counted by the color, there is black and white.

Each mentioned attribute is random:

- Age: Young = 0, Old = 1
- Color (Black, White).

I understand the logic, but I don't know how to send groups of sheep to the machine, and I can't make the counter to increase if I make more sheep. (During the assignation I was asked to do this).

I commented the code for further understanding:
http://gabrielmeono.com/theFarm.zip

```
<?php 
class Sheep{
    //Atributes
    const COLOR_WHITE = 'white';
    const COLOR_BLACK = 'black';
    const AGE_YOUNG = 0;
    const AGE_OLD = 1;

    private $_color;
    private $_age;

    //Random age and color
    public static function makeRandom(){
    if(rand(0, 1)){
        $color = self::COLOR_WHITE;
    }else{
        $color = self::COLOR_BLACK;
    }
        $age = rand(0, 1);
        return new self($color, $age);
    }

    public function __construct($color, $age){
        $this->_color = $color;
        $this->_age = $age;
    }
    //To check if the sheep was created and had all the atributes.
    public function report(){
        echo '<br>This sheep is '.$this->_color.' and '.$this->_age.'<br/>';//Old age is 1. 

        }

}


class machine {
    //The machine should shear wool only if the sheep is old. Old equals 1.
    public function Shear($collector){
        switch($collector)
        {
            case $sheep->_age = 1;
                echo 'Sheep sheared <br/>';
            break;
            default:
                echo 'This sheep is not ready to be sheared <br/>';
            break;

        }
    }
    //Here I should be able to count and separate wool by color.
    public function Counter($whiteWool, $blackWool, $count){ //This is my notion how it should start...Correct me if I'm wrong.


        }
    }

$sheep = Sheep::makeRandom();
$sheep -> report();
$machine = new machine ();
$machine -> Shear(0);
//I don't know how to connect the machine class with the sheep class.
//Batch creation and processing of sheep is beyond my understanding.
?>
```

Comment: Seeing as this is homework I don't want to give too much away. But you should be passing a sheep object to the shear function.

Comment: Gabriel, please consult the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for a better understanding of how this site works. We are happy to help with specific coding problems in your own code (which this isn't). Providing a conceptual understanding should be more in your teacher's domain, I would think.

Comment: I don't think you need a static function to create new sheep, just set the random properties in the function construct and grab it by using `$sheep = new Sheep();`

Comment: @George Cummings, to me this question seems perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, you can add the sheep to the machine through injection.  The `shear` method actually makes the most sense to me.

```
public function Shear(Sheep $sheep) {
   switch ($sheep->age) {} // etc.
}
```

In fact, I would take this a step further by having the sheep react to the shearing.

```
public static function makeRandom() {
   // ...
   return new $age ? OldSheep($color) : YoungSheep($color);
}
```

Or even better:

```
private static $ages = array(0 => 'Old', 1 => 'Young')
public static function makeRandom() {
   // ...
   $sheepclass = $ages[$age] . 'Sheep';
   return new $sheepclass($color);
}
```

Then when it's time for shearing:

```
interface Sheepable {
   function prepareToShear(machine $mach);
}

class OldSheep implements Sheepable {
   public function prepareToShear(machine $mach) {
      echo "Sheep is ready to be shorn";
      $mach->shear($this);
   }
}

class YoungSheep implements Sheepable {
   public function prepareToShear(machine $mach) {
      echo "Sheep is not ready to be shorn";
   }
}

class machine {
   //... etc.
   public function Shear(Sheepable $sheep) {
      $sheep->prepareToShear($this);
   }
}
```

By the way, asking for help with homework tends to get a negative response around here.

Comment: `YoungSheep` don't pupate, emerging from their cocoon as an `OldSheep` :)

Comment: I'm just wondering, why would it be better to have a static factory function than just setting the properties in the construct function and using `new Sheep();` to get a random sheep?

Comment: It is better to have a factory because you can create different objects.  If you could create only one type object, of course using `new ...` would work fine.

Comment: Thanks, I used your example however I'm getting:
 Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to machine::Shear() must implement interface Sheepable, none given, called in theFarm0.php on line 64 and defined in theFarm0.php on line 56

This is the edited php with your corrections:
http://gabrielmeono.com/theFarm0.zip

Comment: Quite simply, you need to pass the Sheep object to the machine class. (`$machine->Shear($sheep)`).  Make sure that you understand what the code is actually doing here.

Comment: Yes, I'm half lost, for me this example is quite complex. I placed $machine->Shear($sheep); and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Pay close attention.  You have `return new self($color, $age)` before the new `return` statement for the specialized sheep classes. This will halt execution of the function and nothing after the `return` statement will execute.  In Java, this would be a parse error (unreachable code).

Answer (score 2):

You can inject the `Sheep` object to the `Machine` by using dependency injection (*todo: google for it*).

e.g.

```
$machine->addSheep($sheep);
```

`addSheep` method should save the `$sheep` object in the class member variable. Other methods may use this variable later.

Answer (score 1):

You can just send $sheep (the object you created) as an argument to a function in the machine class.

Answer (score 1):

I hate farming.
Don't just copypasta. Read through it, ask questions (*but not duplicates*) and we'll be able to assist.

```
interface Animal{
    const AGE_YOUNG = 0;
    const AGE_OLD = 1;
    const COLOR_WHITE = 'white';
    const COLOR_BLACK = 'black';
    public function getAge();
    public function getColor();
}

interface Shearable extends Animal{
    public function shear();
    public function isSheared();
}

class Gorilla implements Shearable{
    // ♫ seeeeeee my vest, see my vest, made of real gorilla chest ♫
}

class Sheep implements Shearable{

    private $_isSheared = false;
    private $_age = null;
    private $_color = null;

    public static function create(){
        $age = rand(0, 1);
        $color = rand(0, 1)
            ? self::COLOR_WHITE
            : self::COLOR_BLACK;
        return new self($age, $color);
    }

    public function __construct($age, $color){
        $this->_age = $age;
        $this->_color = $color;
    }

    public function shear(){
        $this->_isSheared = true;
        return $this;
    }

    public function isSheared(){
        return $this->_isSheared;
    }

    public function getAge(){
        return $this->_age;
    }

    public function getColor(){
        return $this->_color;
    }

}

class Machine{

    private $_wool = array();

    public function shearLine(Array $line){
        $unshearable = array();
        foreach($line as $animal){
            if($this->shear($animal) !== true){
                $unshearable[] = $animal;
            }
        }
        return $unshearable;
    }

    public function shear(Shearable $animal){
        if(!$animal->isSheared() && $animal->getAge() == Shearable::AGE_OLD){
            $this->_wool[] = $animal->shear()->getColor();
            return true;
        }
        return $animal;
    }

    public function getWool(){
        return count($this->_wool);
    }

    public function getWoolByColor($color){
        return count(array_keys($this->_wool, $color));
    }

}

// build a machine
$machine = new Machine();

// brew up some sheep
$lineOfSheep = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 200; $i++){
    $lineOfSheep[] = Sheep::create();
}

//make some underwear
$unshearable = $machine->shearLine($lineOfSheep);

// see how many sheep still need water and sunlight
var_dump(count($unshearable));

// see how much and of what color your underwear will be
var_dump($machine->getWool(), $machine->getWoolByColor(Shearable::COLOR_WHITE));
```

Comment: ♫ ...see this sweater, there's no better, than authentic irish setter; see this hat, t'was my cat, evening wear, vampire bat; these white slippers are albino, african endangered rhino ♫

Comment: Love the Simpsons references, and this is a nice implementation similar to the one I presented.  The only downside is the lack of polymorphism due to the if statements in `shear()`.  You are also making up conditions such as `isSheared()`, or I didn't read properly, but that is sensible.

Comment: Thanks @tandu (*you can't take homework **too** seriously*) Anyways, while true, this implementation doesn't exemplify polymorphism and other OOP purity, it is an effective communication of the intended system. I moved `isSheared()` to the `Shearable` interface to force implementation in the classes. It seemed appropriate to keep these properties as state of the object, as to make easy transition to a more complicated system. For example, for extra credit, one could easily introduce fine-grain "shearing" conditions, or numerical (*rather than essentially boolean*) aging.